How to change background color of chrome://apps
I tried Chrome background color suddenly changed to black but somehow, in light mode, the background for chrome://apps is always black. How can I change that?



source code
I read the code. I think there are two colors, black or white.

black: dark mode
white: light mode.

But when I change the setting to the light mode, this page is still black.
So, there is no way to change...  Especially since it is not an "http" page, so the extension also won't work.

OK, so it is save to say it is a chrome bug?

"chrome://apps has been phased out, encouraging developers to adopt PWAs.", so I think Google won't maintain it anymore.
